# ld: library not found for

Tags: linker, ld

I'm hitting a linker error (compile time, not run time):

```
ld: library not found for -l:/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

That's just the latest version of the error.  I'm trying to link against `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`, and I want to hard-code the path; the library is guaranteed to exist at this path on the platform I'm on.  And it does:

```
bhaller@lanois % ls -l /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  859536 Jan 23 08:59 /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

I have tried:

```
-L/usr/lib/ -llibobjc.A.dylib
-L/usr/lib/ -llibobjc.A
-l/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
-l:/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

In every case I get the same error, that ld couldn't find the library.  But it's right there, and I'm giving the complete path to it!  What am I missing??

Here's the full invocation, with a bunch of other cruft:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -headerpad_max_install_names -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o QtSLiM.app/Contents/MacOS/QtSLiM -L/Users/bhaller/Desktop/QtSLiM QMAKE/QtSLiM/../core/ -L/Users/bhaller/Desktop/QtSLiM QMAKE/QtSLiM/../eidos/ -L/Users/bhaller/Desktop/QtSLiM QMAKE/QtSLiM/../treerec/tskit/ -L/Users/bhaller/Desktop/QtSLiM QMAKE/QtSLiM/../gsl/ -L/Users/bhaller/Desktop/QtSLiM QMAKE/QtSLiM/../eidos_zlib/ -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -rpath @executable_path/Frameworks -rpath /Users/bhaller/Qt5.9.8/5.9.8/clang_64/lib main.o QtSLiMWindow.o QtSLiMAppDelegate.o QtSLiMWindow_glue.o QtSLiMChromosomeWidget.o QtSLiMExtras.o QtSLiMPopulationTable.o QtSLiMIndividualsWidget.o QtSLiMEidosPrettyprinter.o QtSLiMAbout.o QtSLiMPreferences.o QtSLiMSyntaxHighlighting.o QtSLiMFindRecipe.o QtSLiMHelpWindow.o QtSLiMScriptTextEdit.o QtSLiMEidosConsole.o QtSLiMEidosConsole_glue.o QtSLiMConsoleTextEdit.o QtSLiM_SLiMgui.o QtSLiMTablesDrawer.o QtSLiMFindPanel.o QtSLiMGraphView.o QtSLiMGraphView_FixationTimeHistogram.o QtSLiMGraphView_FrequencySpectra.o QtSLiMGraphView_LossTimeHistogram.o QtSLiMGraphView_PopulationVisualization.o QtSLiMGraphView_FitnessOverTime.o QtSLiMGraphView_FrequencyTrajectory.o QtSLiMHaplotypeManager.o QtSLiMHaplotypeOptions.o QtSLiMHaplotypeProgress.o QtSLiMVariableBrowser.o qrc_buttons.o qrc_icons.o qrc_recipes.o qrc_help.o moc_QtSLiMWindow.o moc_QtSLiMAppDelegate.o moc_QtSLiMChromosomeWidget.o moc_QtSLiMExtras.o moc_QtSLiMPopulationTable.o moc_QtSLiMIndividualsWidget.o moc_QtSLiMAbout.o moc_QtSLiMPreferences.o moc_QtSLiMSyntaxHighlighting.o moc_QtSLiMFindRecipe.o moc_QtSLiMHelpWindow.o moc_QtSLiMScriptTextEdit.o moc_QtSLiMEidosConsole.o moc_QtSLiMConsoleTextEdit.o moc_QtSLiMTablesDrawer.o moc_QtSLiMFindPanel.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_FixationTimeHistogram.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_FrequencySpectra.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_LossTimeHistogram.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_PopulationVisualization.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_FitnessOverTime.o moc_QtSLiMGraphView_FrequencyTrajectory.o moc_QtSLiMHaplotypeManager.o moc_QtSLiMHaplotypeOptions.o moc_QtSLiMHaplotypeProgress.o moc_QtSLiMVariableBrowser.o -lcore -leidos -ltskit -lgsl -leidos_zlib -l:/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a -F/Users/bhaller/Qt5.9.8/5.9.8/clang_64/lib
ld: library not found for -l:/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [QtSLiM.app/Contents/MacOS/QtSLiM] Error 1
make: *** [sub-QtSLiM-make_first] Error 2
```

I feel like I must just be an idiot, but I can't see it.  Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linkage command shows that your linker is the OS X linker. Refer to it's [manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/)
with respect to the `-l` option:

> -lx
>
> This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or libx.a in the library search path.
>   If string x is of the form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places, but
>   without prepending `lib` or appending `.a` or `.dylib` to the filename.

This will show you why all of:

```
-L/usr/lib/ -llibobjc.A.dylib
-L/usr/lib/ -llibobjc.A
-l/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
-l:/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

are wrong. In each of your attempts, where `name` is whatever you have typed after `-l`,
the linker will be directed to search for `libname.dylib` or `libname.a`. Of course
none of those files - e.g. `liblibobjc.A.dylib.dylib`,`liblibobjc.A.dylib.a` - exists
in `/usr/lib/` or any of the other specified or default search directories, and
in the third and fourth attempts, `libname.(dylib|a)` resolves to strings that that
cannot even possibly be unqualified filenames.

Your final variation evidently wants to used `-l:name` in an attempt to make the linker
search precisely for `name` ( = `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`). However,
`-l:name` is an option for the [GNU Binutils linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options), (the default linker in Linux)
and as per the documentation, is not an option for the OS X linker. (Furthermore, that option of the Binutils linker
directs the linker to search in each directory for a file with the exact unqualified name `name`, which  `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`
could not be).

To get the linker to locate `libobjc.A.dylib` in `/usr/lib/` you require the option:

```
-lobjc.A
```

Consider for example the other `-l` options in your your linkage command:

```
-lcore -leidos -ltskit -lgsl -leidos_zlib
```

Before you try that however, I suggest that you check in `/usr/lib` for the existence
of a symbolic link:

```
libobjc -> libobjc.A
```

This would indicate that `libobjc.A` is *the version* of `libobjc` that your toolchain
is configured to select, and that the linkage option you require is simply:

```
-lobjc
```

The search option `-L/usr/lib/` is in any case redundant, since `/usr/lib/` is a default
linker search directory.

Comment: Great answer; I didn't realize `ld` was so different on different platforms, and had googled "man ld", because for some reason my macOS system wouldn't show me the man page for `ld`.  Regarding libobjc.A vs. libobjc: yes, there is a symlink, and normally I would use it since I'm familiar with that convention.  But https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime?language=objc says "Objective-C runtime library... shared library found at /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib."  That seems to suggest that I am supposed to link against libobjc.A.dylib directly, for some reason...?